# Algorithm to generate triangular mesh from closed path

Tags: algorithm, geometry, point, mesh

I would like to know how to generate triangular mesh from a closed path. The data I have is a set of vertices and edges where the 1st vertex connect with 2nd vertex, 2nd vertex is connected to 3rd vertex etc. The last vertex would then connect back to first vertex to form a loop.

I wonder how would I convert this data into triangular mesh plane.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation

Comment: Yes, from what you describe, you have a polygon. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247994/simple-2d-polygon-triangulation